# How can I allow slashes in my Express routes?

Tags: node.js, express

I'm attempting to implement permalinks, in the form `/2013/02/16/title-with-hyphens`. I'd like to use route parameters. If I try the following route:

```
app.get('/:href', function(req, res) { });
```

...then I get a 404, presumably because Express is only looking for one parameter, and thinks that there are 4.

I can work around it with `/:y/:m/:d/:t`, but this forces my permalinks to be of that form permanently.

How do I get route parameters to include slashes?

Answer (score 36, accepted):

Use a regular expression instead of a string.

```
app.get(/^\/(.+)/, function(req, res) {
    var href = req.params[0]; // regexp's numbered capture group
});
```

---

Note that you cannot use the string syntax (`app.get('/:href(.+)')`) because Express only allows a small subset of regular expressions in route strings, and it uses those regular expressions as a conditional check for *that particular component* of the route.  It does not capture the matched content in the conditional, nor does it allow you to match across components (parts of the URL separated by slashes).

For example:

```
app.get('/:compa([0-9])/:compb([a-z]/')
```

This route only matches if the first component (*compa*) is a single digit, and the second component (*compb*) is a single letter a-z.

`'/:href(.+)'` says "match the first component only if the content is anything", which doesn't make much sense; that's the default behavior anyway.  Additionally, if you examine [the source](https://github.com/visionmedia/express/blob/3.1.0/lib/utils.js#L262-282), you'll see that Express is actually forcing the dot in that conditional to be literal.

For example, `app.get('/:href(.+)')` actually compiles into:

```
 /^\/(?:(\.+))\/?$/i
```

Notice that your `.` was escaped, so this route will only match one or more periods.

Answer (score 37):

It seems that `app.get("/:href(*)", ...)` works fine (at least in Express 4). You will get your parameter value in `req.params.href`.

It will also be fired by `/` route, which is probably not what you want. You can avoid it by setting `app.get('/', ...)` elsewhere in your app or explicitly checking for an empty string.

Comment: I was going to settle for /* but you nailed it

Answer (score 2):

You can use this if your parameters has include slashes in it

```
app.get('/:href(*)', function(req, res) { ... })
```

It works for me. In my case, I used parameters like `ABC1/12345/6789(10)`.
Hopefully this useful.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with regex routing

```
app.get('/:href(\d+\/\d+\/\d+\/*)', function(req, res) { });
```

I don't know if the regex is right, but you get the idea

EDIT:

I don't think the above works, but this does

```
app.get(/^\/(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(.*)/, function(req, res) { });
```

Going to `http://localhost:3000/2012/08/05/hello-i-must-be` yeilds `req.params = [ '2012', '08', '05', 'hello-i-must-be' ]`

Comment: I'm trying `app.get('/:href(.+)', ...` with no luck. What am I missing?

Comment: I don't think you can pass a regexp inside a route string.  You have to pass a regexp object; see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14915608/201952).

Comment: I was going off the above mentioned stackoverflow answer

Comment: I couldn't get the first to work but I edited it with the correct regex and working example

Comment: @RogerLipscombe: That post is about restricting what a particular component of a route matches; you cannot use that syntax to insert an arbitrary regex.  I've expanded my answer with more details about why.