# How can I get a path as a key in express?

Tags: node.js, express, parameters, infinite

My current route lookup is `app.get('/s/:key', ...`, but there is a good reason to be able to get other keys passed in that same way.  It is possible that I'll require getting paths that way as well--so basically I want to capture `app.get('/s/:key/more/stuff/here/', ...` and be able to read key independently of the `/more/stuff/here` portion.  I don't have an issue with capturing the other parameters as an array of arguments and then concatenating them, but I don't know how to do that--I get 404s if I try to capture anything other than `/s/:key` with nothing following.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Sorry, I'm kinda confused. What do you want to capture? The `/more/stuff/here`? And you get 404 if you use `/s/:key` as your route?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

String routes in expressjs is like a regular expression so with that being said, you can use asterisk `*` as a wildcard:

```
app.get('/s/:key/*', function(req, res, next) {
    var key = req.params.key;
    var someOtherParams = req.params[0];
});
```

Which will be:

- http://example.com/s/1/some/other/stuff - `req.params.key` = `1`, `req.params[0]` = `some/other/stuff`

Then from there you can parse your wildcard. Like split it by `/`.

---

OR if you want to be strict that it should not have other characters than alphanumeric, slashes and dashes, use regex directly on your route. Because on expressjs, you can't do a string route containing a single param with slashes then use regex on it and capture that param. It's a bit odd but you can look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14915496/how-can-i-allow-slashes-in-my-express-routes) for the explanation.

Anyway, for the code to do a regex on your route:

```
app.get(/s\/([A-Za-z0-9]+)\/(([A-Za-z\-\/]+)*$)/, function(req, res, next) {
        var key = req.params[0];
        var someOtherParams = req.params[1];
    });
```

Which is capturing 2 groups (`req.params[0]`-->`([A-Za-z0-9]+)` and `req.params[1]`-->`(([A-Za-z\-\/]+)*$)`).

The first group is actually your key, and the second group is the param that can contain alpha-numeric, dash and slash. Which you can parse or split by slashes. This way, your route is strict enough to not contain any other characters.

Result will be:

- http://example.com/s/1/some/other/stuff - `req.params[0]` = `1`, `req.params[1]` = `some/other/stuff`
- http://example.com/s/1/some-other/stuff - `req.params[0]` = `1`, `req.params[1]` = `some-other/stuff`
- http://example.com/s/1/some/other-weird/stuff - `req.params[0]` = `1`, `req.params[1]` = `some/other-weird/stuff`
- http://example.com/s/1/some/other/stuff-one - `req.params[0]` = `1`, `req.params[1]` = `some/other/stuff-one`
- http://example.com/s/1/some&other/stuff - Error 404, `&` is not permitted in your regex

Answer (score 1):

Try using this:

```
app.get('/s/:key/*', function(req, res, next) {
    var key = req.params.key;
    var restAfterKey = req.params[0];
    // Work on response or pass on to next();
}
```

This way in your request handler callback:

- `req.params.key` is the value of the :key placeholder
- `req.params[0]` will hold everything that follows after the :key placeholder