# node.js - need to validate my input field

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, ejs

I'm going through a code boot camp on Udemy.

The challenge has been to create a blog site using Node.js and ejs. I've completed the challenge and the blog site works. However, I want to change one thing and I'm struggling to find a workable solution.

My app.js file will 'push' the post i create in the compose page, to the home page and then redirect me there. And then the home page gives me a '... read more' after 100 characters. If the title of the post has a '/' in it, for example '1/2/22', then when I click the read more button I get an error 'Cannot GET /posts/1/2/22'. I understand why I get this error so I'm hoping someone can help me with preventing someone from typing a '/' or other special characters into the input field.

Ive tried regEx but cant get it to work right.

```
<!-- My home page -->

<h1>Home</h1>
  <p>
    <%= startingContent %>
  </p>


  <% posts.forEach(function(post){ %>

    <h1>
      <%=post.title%>
    </h1>
    <p>
      <%=post.content.substring(0, 100) + " ..." %>
        <a href="/posts/<%= post.title %>">Read More</a>
    </p>


    <% }) %>
```

```
<!--  this is the page to type the post and submit it -->
<h1>Compose</h1>
    <form class="" action="/compose" method="post">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Title</label>
        <input class="form-control" type="text" name="postTitle">
        <label>Post</label>
        <textarea class="form-control" name="postBody" rows="5" cols="30"></textarea>
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit" name="button">Publish</button>
    </form>
```

```
//app.js file

const express = require("express");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const ejs = require("ejs");
const _ = require("lodash");
const port = 3000;

const homeStartingContent = "Lacus vel facilisis volutpat est velit egestas dui id ornare. Semper auctor neque vitae tempus quam. Sit amet cursus sit amet dictum sit amet justo. Viverra tellus in hac habitasse. Imperdiet proin fermentum leo vel orci porta. Donec ultrices tincidunt arcu non sodales neque sodales ut. Mattis molestie a iaculis at erat pellentesque adipiscing. Magnis dis parturient montes nascetur ridiculus mus mauris vitae ultricies. Adipiscing elit ut aliquam purus sit amet luctus venenatis lectus. Ultrices vitae auctor eu augue ut lectus arcu bibendum at. Odio euismod lacinia at quis risus sed vulputate odio ut. Cursus mattis molestie a iaculis at erat pellentesque adipiscing.";
const aboutContent = "Hac habitasse platea dictumst vestibulum rhoncus est pellentesque. Dictumst vestibulum rhoncus est pellentesque elit ullamcorper. Non diam phasellus vestibulum lorem sed. Platea dictumst quisque sagittis purus sit. Egestas sed sed risus pretium quam vulputate dignissim suspendisse. Mauris in aliquam sem fringilla. Semper risus in hendrerit gravida rutrum quisque non tellus orci. Amet massa vitae tortor condimentum lacinia quis vel eros. Enim ut tellus elementum sagittis vitae. Mauris ultrices eros in cursus turpis massa tincidunt dui.";
const contactContent = "Scelerisque eleifend donec pretium vulputate sapien. Rhoncus urna neque viverra justo nec ultrices. Arcu dui vivamus arcu felis bibendum. Consectetur adipiscing elit duis tristique. Risus viverra adipiscing at in tellus integer feugiat. Sapien nec sagittis aliquam malesuada bibendum arcu vitae. Consequat interdum varius sit amet mattis. Iaculis nunc sed augue lacus. Interdum posuere lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipiscing elit. Pulvinar elementum integer enim neque. Ultrices gravida dictum fusce ut placerat orci nulla. Mauris in aliquam sem fringilla ut morbi tincidunt. Tortor posuere ac ut consequat semper viverra nam libero.";

const app = express();

app.set('view engine', 'ejs');

app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));
app.use(express.static("public"));

let posts = [];

app.get("/", (req, res) => {
  res.render("home", {
    startingContent: homeStartingContent,
    posts: posts
  });
});

app.get("/about", (req, res) => {
  res.render("about", {
    aboutContent: aboutContent
  });
});

app.get("/contact", (req, res) => {
  res.render("contact", {
    contactContent: contactContent
  });
});

app.get("/compose", (req, res) => {
  res.render("compose");
});

app.post("/compose", (req, res) => {
  const post = {
    title: req.body.postTitle,
    content: req.body.postBody
  };

  posts.push(post);
  res.redirect("/");

});

app.get("/posts/:postName", (req, res) => {
  const requestedTitle = _.lowerCase(req.params.postName);

  posts.forEach((post) => {
    const storedTitle = _.lowerCase(post.title);

    if (storedTitle === requestedTitle) {
      res.render("post", {
        title: post.title,
        content: post.content
      });
    }
  });

});

app.listen(port, () => {
  console.log(`Server is running on port ${port}`);
});
```

Comment: Might it make more sense to encode the param if that's a valid post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'Cannot GET /posts/1/2/22'

Either you do app.get("/posts/:postName(*)"

Ref: [Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14915496/how-can-i-allow-slashes-in-my-express-routes/24366031)

Comment: I get the cannot GET error because of the / in the title.  but if I were to do app.get("/posts/:postName(*), am I inserting something in place of the *? Sorry if thats a dumb question. Im still new to node and express.. actually Im pretty new to all of this so any clarification is helpful.

Comment: What suppouse to happen, is if you do /posts/:postName(*) and then if you visit with /posts/1/2/22 then you req.params.postName is equal to "/1/2/22" type of string.
This is me without testing tho.

Comment: adding (*) to the end of /posts/:postName worked.  Thanks!